# How to Generate Dashboard Report from JMeter GUI ?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I can generate dashboard report from command line... but i have to execute test with command line for the same .... Can we generate Dashboard report from Jmeter GUI or run test from GUI and get dashboard report for the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short, yes you have to run test from GUI and get dashboard report for the same.

Add a listener to your test script in GUI mode. From every test, you can generate report file (.jtl file) in default CSV format.

In your listeners, you can save your report file (.jtl file) like this. Just put the full path of your file and the run the test.

[image]

This will automatically generates the .jtl/.csv reports after test completion.

Then you can read and process samples from CSV files to generate HTML files containing graph views.

Now, Generating report from the existing .jtl results file:

```
jmeter -g /path/to/jtl/file -o /where/you/want/to/store/dashboard
```

For more, follow this [referrence](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report).

Comment: Sorry i will modify my question, i can generate dashboard report  from command line by using './jmeter -n -t /path to TestPlan.jmx -l result.csv -e -o path to output folder - dashboard report' BUT AT THE SAME TIME I WANT TO GENERATE JTL, CAN I DO THAT FROM COMMAND LINE AT SAME TIME? i know how to achieve this by adding listener to test plan and then running  from command line to get csv and dashboard report and browse the listner path from test plan for jtl....BUT i WANT TO ACHIEVE THIS THROUGH COMMAND LINE AT SAME TIME WITHOUT ADDING LISTENER TO TEST PLAN

Comment: You're the savior! But why it's not available in GUI mode out-of-the-box??

Comment: @Daria, JMeter GUI is for debugging purpose only. It consumes a lot of memory in GUI mode.

Answer (score 1):

As of JMeter 3.0 or 3.1, HTML report can be generated in 2 ways:

- Non GUI mode at end of load test
- On demand from command line using an existing CSV file

See this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

Generating a report for a load test ran in GUI will never be possible because it's a bad practice to Load Test from GUI.

But it may be possible in the future to generate a report from an existing CSV file and from the GUI:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59896

Comment: Sorry i will modify my question, i can generate dashboard report from command line by using './jmeter -n -t /path to TestPlan.jmx -l result.csv -e -o path to output folder - dashboard report' BUT AT THE SAME TIME I WANT TO GENERATE JTL, CAN I DO THAT FROM COMMAND LINE AT SAME TIME? i know how to achieve this by adding listener to test plan and then running from command line to get csv and dashboard report and browse the listner path from test plan for jtl....BUT i WANT TO ACHIEVE THIS THROUGH COMMAND LINE AT SAME TIME WITHOUT ADDING LISTENER TO TEST PLAN

Comment: you must not modify a question for which an answer has been provided and validated. ask a new one